# Function istops process

Tags: php, function

I have a process which works just fine on it's own but fails to render any info from within a function.

This works:

```
if ($totalRows_menu > 0) {
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row_menu = mysql_fetch_array($menu)) {
        echo "<li>" . $row_menu['m3menu_item'] . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
```

but this doesn't:

```
function m3menu()
{
if ($totalRows_menu > 0) {
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row_menu = mysql_fetch_array($menu)) {
        echo "<li>" . $row_menu['m3menu_item'] . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
}
echo m3menu();
```

Comment: How about just `m3menu();` instead of `echo m3menu();`?

Comment: `$totalRows_menu` and `$menu` are not available in the function. Read up on variable scopes. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php Keep in mind that the use of global variables is generally not recommended.

Comment: Lex - Your comment threw me. I am quite a novice. I have to declare within the function?

Comment: I note this is marked as duplicate by some members. Had I known the term "variable scopes" and usage chances are I would not have need to ask the question. I did search but sometimes you can't search when you don't know what the solution is. Easy on the learners please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lex says your variables are not available in the scope of the function. You can either pass them into the function when you call it, or you can use `global`

Also, your function is `echo`ing rather than `return`ing the HTML so there is no need for `echo m3menu();` you should just call the function like `m3menu();`, or you could `return` the HTML from the function and then `echo` out the value.

Method 1

```
function m3menu( $totalRows_menu, $menu )
{
    if ($totalRows_menu > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row_menu = mysql_fetch_array($menu)) {
            echo "<li>" . $row_menu['m3menu_item'] . "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

m3menu($totalRows_menu, $menu);
```

Method 2

```
function m3menu()
{
    global $totalRows_menu;
    global $menu;

    if ($totalRows_menu > 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
        while($row_menu = mysql_fetch_array($menu)) {
            echo "<li>" . $row_menu['m3menu_item'] . "</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

m3menu();
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. I learned something and MajorCaiger method 2 did exactly what I wanted.